# How to run docker file in jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins

I want to run docker file on Jenkins , and execute the shell scripts in the job,i found the plugin:docker slaves plugin, but it seems doesn't work,Anyone have better suggestion or how to use the plugin correct?, thanks!!

Comment: Have you read through [Using Docker with Pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/) in the Jenkins docs?  What have you tried so far, and when you say "doesn't work", what actually happens?

Answer (score 1):

You can run bash script under **Build -> Execute shell**. If you are interested to docker container using Jenkins you can utilize the Execute Shell option. But make sure Jenkins have access to Docker.

```
cd /path_to_you_docker_file/
echo "building docker image for"
docker built -t alpine .
echo "starting alpien container"
docker run --name alpine -dit  alpine
echo "All running containers in Jenkins servers"
docker ps
```

You can execute multiple Shell in build section.

[image]

You will see the container in Jenkins name alpine.

The plugin can be used better with pipeline, not with a bash script.

```
docker.image('ruby:2.3.1').inside {

    stage("Install Bundler") {
      sh "gem install bundler --no-rdoc --no-ri"
    }

    stage("Use Bundler to install dependencies") {
      sh "bundle install"
    }
}
```

To run with the plugin you can check this [article](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/) to configure.